# jQuery stop function running several times over

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a slider which I'm trying to pause and then resume when a user hovers over it:

```
    var run_state = true;
    var body_left = 0;
    function slider() {
        if (run_state == true) {
            $.get('http://mydomain.com/ajaxpage', function(data){
                var data_one = $(data).find('#container_sub').html();
                $('#container').append(data_one);
                body_left = body_left - 201;
                $('#container').animate({marginLeft: body_left+'px'}, 400);
                setTimeout(slider, 3000);
            });         
        }       
    }

    $('body').on('mouseover', '#container', function(){
        run_state = false;
    });
    $('body').on('mouseleave', '#container', function(){
        run_state = true;
        slider();
    });
```

I manage to pause the slider with `mouseover` but when it comes to `mouseleave`, the `slider()` function runs several times without stopping, causing several animations to run one after the other.

My question is, on `mouseleave`how do I force the slider to finish the current animation, pause 3 seconds before running it again?

Thanks

Comment: Please post the function content of `front_page_slider_next_product`

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL sorry, I meant that to be function `slider`

Comment: Are you really getting new content with ajax every three seconds, and just appending to the same element *forever* ?

Comment: Anyway, try -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/s9DLs/

Comment: @adeneo Yea I am getting new content. Basically the ajax calls to a page which fetches a new random content from the db every time the page is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setInterval for that;

```
var body_left = 0;
var myTimer;
function getContent() {
    $.get('http://mydomain.com/ajaxpage', function(data){
        var data_one = $(data).find('#container_sub').html();
        $('#container').append(data_one);
        body_left = body_left - 201;
        $('#container').animate({marginLeft: body_left+'px'}, 400);
        setTimeout(slider, 3000);
    }); 
}

function run() {
    myTimer = setInterval(function() {
        getContent();
    }, 3000);
}

$('#test').on('mouseover', function(){
    clearInterval(myTimer);

});
$('#test').on('mouseleave', function(){
    run();
});
```

You can see demo here : **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TeMmG/3/)**

Comment: I just tried that, the problem is when the function calls `setTimeout(slider, 3000);` to continue the slider, it sees that `run_state=false` and won't start again.

Comment: I just tried your fiddle as well as tested on my end. If you hover on and off quickly over the slided- in your fiddle, you'll notice that instead of waiting for 3 seconds before the next slided- is appended, the script quickly appends a whole bunch of them. What I need is for the 3 second delay to be respected by the script regardless how fast or how many times I hover over the slided-

Comment: @user2028856 You are right, I have updated my answer and demo. I have used setInterval to make your case. Please see my updated answer and demo